# Represent decimal first with point, then comma

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp-net-core-spa-services

I found plenty of solutions with first comma and then point, and I want something like this: `133.000,00`

What I tried so far: `@item.Price.ToString("C3", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"))`

and

`@String.Format("{0:#.##0,######}", item.Price)`

In second formatting I am only getting `133000.00`

Comment: can we clarify: the price you want to represent - is it "133 thousand", or is it "133 point zero"?

Comment: @MarcGravell it is "133 thousand"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean (after `var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");`)

```
var s = price.ToString("#,##0.00####", culture);
```

or:

```
var s = string.Format(culture, "{0:#,##0.00####}", price);
```

In both cases you need to *pass in* the culture to use, and: `.` in the format string means "the culture's decimal point token", and `,` in the format string means "the culture's thousands separator token". Note I used `.00##` at the end because you seem to want two decimal places even if they are zeros.

Comment: I just want to mention I am doing this in asp.net core, razor page, I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
item.Price.ToString("#,#0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"))
```